# Bootstrap Layout breaks on iPhone vertical layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, responsive-design

Please help, I have a very simple page layout, that for some reason breaks when viewed on the iPhone in vertical orientation. I seems like the defined col-6 divs are being collapsed too much. Is there something wrong with my layout, or is it bootstrap messing up?

PAGE LINK: http://goo.gl/kzy2Ly

Answer (score 1):

So far as I can see it looks good, or I don't understand what should be wrong, except of the big buttons in the mobile view.

The only thing I found was the orientation change who doesn't works well. 
But this is easy to fix with adapting your meta viewport like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```